# How to use a select2 with ajax and coldfusion

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, jquery-select2

I am having a horrible time trying to change my select to a select 2. I have the query below that retrieves the data I need for my select that is in a separate CFC file:

```
<cffunction name="getChecklistsForSelect" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="ds" required="no" default=""/>
    <cfargument name="oname" required="no" default=""/>
    <cfargument name="loc" required="no" default=""/>
    <cfset var results = structNew()>
    <cfset var checklists = arrayNew(1)>

    <cfquery name="local.qGetChecklists" datasource="#ds#">
        select checklist as displaymodule, checklistvalue as valuemodule
        from checklisttable ct WITH (NOLOCK)
        and ct.orgname=N'#arguments.oname#'
        and ct.location=N'#arguments.loc#'
        group by displaymodule,valuemodule
        order by 1;
    </cfquery>

    <!--- use default keys: "id" and "text" --->  
    <cfloop query="local.qGetChecklists" startRow="1" endRow="#local.qGetChecklists.recordCount#">
        <cfset elem = structNew()>
        <cfset elem["id"] = local.qGetChecklists.valuemodule>
        <cfset elem["text"] = local.qGetChecklists.displaymodule>
        <cfset arrayAppend(checklists, elem)>
    </cfloop>

    <!--- package the results into a structure --->  
    <cfset results["total"] = local.qGetChecklists.recordCount>
    <cfset results["checklists"] = checklists>
    <cfcontent type="application/json" reset="true">
    <cfoutput>#serializeJSON(results)#</cfoutput>

    <cfabort/> 
</cffunction>
```

And the front end looks like this in my cfm file:

```
<select name="checklist" id="checklist"></select>
```

I'm not even going to post the jquery because its embarrassing and I haven't got even close to figuring it out yet.

Thankyou for any help!

Comment: Check this: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

Comment: To start, your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: NEVER output text from inside of a function. EVER. Get rid of the `<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(results)#</cfoutput>` and the `<cfabort />` and replace it with return `<cfreturn results />`. Then, when you call this from jQuery use `{path to file}myFile.cfc?method=getChecklistsForSelect&returnFormat=json` as well as passing in the arguments.

Comment: Also, if you want your function to be available to js, the access must be remote, not public.